# How to connect PostgreSQL with hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, hapi.js

> Does anyone managed to setup with `PostgreSQL` with `Hapi.js` framework? I have been looking for answers to this but *no avail*.

I have the server all setup and ready to connect with PostgreSQL to the application. What is the **most appropriate approach** to connect the database with `pg-promise`?

Also, what is the most **efficient and shorter** way of writing this code for this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) with Hapi.js see [hapi-pg-promise](https://github.com/dszczyt/hapi-pg-promise).

Answer (score -1):

Most shorter way to connect hapi + postgreSQL is using [K7](https://github.com/thebergamo/k7) and the Sequelize connector. You can find an example of using it the project [cart](https://github.com/thebergamo/cart) there you can see the example of using it.